# icicles execute action on all candidates

Tags: icicles

I generally use `icicles` to execute a large number of parallel actions.

One thing I find myself doing often is narrowing the number of candidates, and spamming <kbd>C-<next></kbd> to execute an action on all of the matching candidates.

I've been through the docs, and I can't find a more efficient way to do it. Is there a more finger-friendly way to execute an action on all current candidates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `C-!` to act on all candidates.

(`M-!` is similar, but slightly different.  And `C-|` and `M-|` are parallel, but they perform an [alternative action](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_More_About_Multi-Commands#AlternativeActions) on all candidates.)

See [**Icicles - Choose All Completion Candidates**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Choose_All_Candidates).

This is also explained at other locations in the doc (e.g. with examples).  See, for example, the intro section [Icicles - A Nutshell View](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Nutshell_View) -- [this example](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Nutshell_View#SecondExampleMultiCompletion), for instance.